# grep statement for (...=...) not working

Tags: regex, bash, grep, pattern-matching

Within a group of files, I'd like to find all lines containing 
`if ( ... = ... )`

but not `if ( ... != ... )`  or `if ( ... == ... )`

This is the last thing I tried, which seems like it should work:

`find . -type f -name "*.mm" | xargs grep -E "if ([^=!]*=[^!=]*)"`

I want a pattern that says `if (`, then anything but `!`, then a singular `=`, then anything, then `)`.

But I'm getting `bash: !]*=[^!=]*: event not found`

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try single quotes, `!` inside double quotes has special meaning.

Comment: @redneb no error, but now I am getting stuff that has ( .. == .. ), which I don't want

Comment: ahh figured it out. `find . -type f -name "*.mm" | xargs grep -E 'if ([^=!]* = [^!=]*)'`

Comment: The quantifier shouldn't be `*`, because that's zero or more and will always match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `grep -E` - the `-E` flag makes `(` and `)` special characters used for regex grouping; they no longer match literal parentheses.  Thus, for the most part, your regular expression was equivalent to `if [^=!]*=[^!=]*` - which means, after it found the first `=`, it would match even if another `=` followed it.  Try this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mm" | xargs grep -E 'if \([^=!]*=[^=!]*\)'
```

Comment: In this case, isn't it better to remove the useless `-E` instead of escaping the parenthesis?